# Passing foreign key value from drop down list when onchage event is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've built my project using ASP.NET MVC and I also used entity framework to build some automatic CRUD pages. There are two tables like below, the problem is I want to call a method in my controller whenever the drop down list is changed.

[image]

In the "Create" page of Ticket the list of Customer is loaded in a drop down list but **I need to pass the key of the selected Customer to one of the methods in my controller**. Other questions related to this topic were answered with javascript method but which is either limited to the list of drop down list created manually not from database or it loads from one database itself not from another table via foreign key.
here is the code 
My view:

```
@model Myproject.Models.Ticket
    <html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Ticket</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

...
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerId, "CustomerId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("CustomerId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control",
        // I'm trying to call my method here 
                   @onchange = @TicketsController.GetDiscount(CustomerId)

               })
        // I'd like to show the return value of the method in a label 
...

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>   
    }


</body>
</html>
```

My method in the controller:

```
public string GetDiscount(int CustomerId)
        {
           //return something
        }
```

Imagine if the primary key of the first customer is 10 and the first customer is selected, I need to pass number 10 to my controller and get the result of that method and show the result in one label.

Comment: How are you rendering the Customer dropdown ? What method you want to call on the onchange ?

Comment: There are two render files in my view referring to Jquery. I just created views and controllers automatically from entity framework through scaffolding process.